# Generic Nested Value Getter in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I'm trying to write a TS function which gets a nested value from given object. That object can be one of several types so I'm using generics. However, TS complains so I feel like I'm misunderstanding how generics work in TS:

```
interface BaseValueObject<T> {
  value: T | null
}

type StringValue = BaseValueObject<string>
type NumberValue = BaseValueObject<number>

interface FormAData {
  name: StringValue,
  age: NumberValue
}

interface FormBData {
  height: NumberValue
  nickname: StringValue
}

interface FormA {
  data: FormAData
}

interface FormB {
  data: FormBData
}

type Form = FormA | FormB

const getFormValue =
  <F extends Form, P extends keyof F['data']>(form: F, property: P) =>
    form['data'][property]['value'] // Type 'P' cannot be used to index type 'FormAData | FormBData'
```

Desired usage:

```
const formARecord: FormA = {
  data: {
    name: {
      value: 'Joe'
    },
    age: {
      value: 50
    }
  }
}
const joesAge = getFormValue(formARecord, 'age')
console.log(joesAge) // 50
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QGpwDYCuEA8gEYBWECYAPACoB8yA3gFDLIBu+RAXMnWQAfZCAJ48rAL6tWYAJ4AHFAGUwUUAHNchFAF40mHDxIUqtDOq0M5SlADkCAW1LQdRZAfRZ3pytRoxF2gbVlBIWEQUADEAeygnAEEAETgwOBZ2UTgnCH41DRBtEwAaLLhNPORHYKhfaVlw6HgkZDiE1FT0zI4ACwhgTV6wfhrXOpMskGAEAGsQHKqCrXqZMPBmqLb4pJ7kABM0uH52pK64BvWIlpid1D3D9JO788uFZW2Ez0-dkVPUWQIWIgSzIGA7RIAJSo8X2zwSiW+bA4j2Oew4C1y-GRHA43F0-AA5AApWIQQlZDhSMq45AVKo42n4vjIACsAAZKcgZFTLkCQWBkJUwKdfJ4sjRosgIAAPSAgfYYH4lZAABWlcogCqVswg8liMDaAG1CajCQBdBgACnBCROKsUUFiyigCn4qoAlJ4bLTbU4TWbzUbHc7oAog4TmeTzcgAPSx5AAUSgTqg-DodmQhNVhOQCDgIBAsUFrmQBCw+2QYFiyFA+1lVczhNOKSOwh+nSOFNY-NB5DJGESlW+wtFJhtEOhQKg+xVhPphI9PeBGFieAgADo8LFNFb+xBB5UvfG2eygA)

**Solution**

Here's what I ended up doing, similar to what @jered suggested in his answer:

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QGpwDYCuEA8gEYBWECYAPACoB8yA3gFDLIBu+RAXMnWQAfZCAJ48rAL6tWYAJ4AHFAGUwUUAHNchFAF40mHDxIUqtDOq0M5SlADkCAW1LQdRZAfRZ3pytRoxF2gbBWVkX09kNQ0QbRNhZEdgqF9ZUEhYRBRvCAAxAHsoJwARODA4FnZkAG1FKALlKAV+S1jNAF1+NJlWDOh4JGRC4oBBMorkCAAPSBAAEwxDLBHS8sq2DhA4Jwh+GK1fABpquE09pOdXVJNpdPAB7OGip1QJypm5xeX8l-eOTbIAAWEGAmiBYH4yWuaS2wAQAGttrt9lY4j17plBihVqMqhx5ut+Lj3nc+g8skNVqh8chCRViS83usyWEcS8orjEtTZAgCiBLMgYC9RgAlKhFeaMsZRQH0uD8QFbHYXJUcbi6fgAcgAUgUIFrqhwpCcOBwzqqjWaNXxkABWAAMVpkxrJfIFYGQ5zAq0iemqNDyU1mEAWS1WR2QAAVg18lgiIPICjBhjUtfKtR0GAAKYXFYmR+qNaAtaMASk8NjNQpeaYzHTqDSaCgbWptBo6vP5gvI+owo3OUW9vpMuZF4r5UHmka1Fq1ZdY7owBTwEAAdHgCpps72IP3zhWAPSH+0OoA)

Basically the lesson is to make explicit any invariants you have your typings. In my case, I wasn't formally telling the compiler that *every* property `FormAData` and `FormBData` adhered to the same interface. I was able to do so by extending them from this base interface:

```
...
type Value = StringValue | NumberValue

interface BaseFormData {
  [property: string]: Value
}

interface FormAData extends BaseFormData {
  ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should extend your declaration of generics to the "form" interfaces themselves.

In this case you need to give TypeScript a way to "infer" what the type of the `data` property of the `form` will be, in order for `property` to properly index it.

The way you have it written currently gives an error because you can't use `keyof` to extract the properties of a union type. Consider this example:

```js
type Foo = {
  fooProperty: string;
}
type Bar = {
  barProperty: string;
}
type Baz = Foo | Bar;
type Qux = keyof Baz; // type Qux = never
```

What type is `Qux` supposed to be? It can't be the keys of two different types simultaneously, so it ends up being of type `never` which is not very useful for indexing properties of an object.

Instead, consider if your base `Form` type was itself a generic, that you know should always have a `data` property, but which the specific type of that `data` property is unknown until it is actually utilized. Fortunately, you could still constrain some aspects of `data` to ensure enforcements of its structure across your app:

```js
interface FormDataType {
  [key: string]: StringValue | NumberValue;
};

interface Form<T extends FormDataType> {
  data: T
};
```

Then when you write your flavors of `Form` that have more specific type definitions for the `data` property, you can do so like this:

```js
type FormA = Form<{
  name: StringValue,
  age: NumberValue
}>;

type FormB = Form<{
  height: NumberValue
  nickname: StringValue
}>;
```

In a way this is sort of like "extending" the type, but in a way that allows TypeScript to use the `Form` generic to *infer* (literally) the type of `data` later on.

Now we can rewrite the `getFormValue()` function's generic types to match the `Form` generics in the function signature. Ideally the return type of the function would be perfectly inferred just from the function parameters and function body, but in this case I didn't find a good way to structure the generics so that everything was seamlessly inferred. Instead, we can directly cast the return type of the function. This has the benefit of 1. still checking that `form["data"]` exists and matches the `FormDataType` structure we established earlier, and 2. inferring the *actual* type of the value returned from calling `getFormValue()`, increasing your overall type checking confidence.

```
const getFormValue = <
  F extends Form<FormDataType>,
  P extends keyof F["data"]
>(
  form: F,
  property: P
) => {
  return form["data"][property].value as F["data"][P]["value"];
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QGpwDYCuEA8gEYBWECYAPACoB8yA3gFDLIBu%20RAXMnWQAfZCAJ48rAL6tWYAJ4AHFAGUwUUAHNchFAF40mHDxIUqtDOq0M5SlADkCAW1LQdRZAfRZ3pytRoxF2gbVlBIWEQUADEAeygnABE4MDg6OxZ2ZABtAGsIeX5LDRBNAF1%20NRLtE2FkR2CoXwBuaVaw8Gh4JGQ4hPpkCAAPSBAAEwxe%20KSUtLsmNg4x2f46NtkFZSmEgEFPbacaRdE4JwhKq1LfABosuE1z%20udXJpNpBnbNmOnUfb7D44ACwgwE0gLA-AaL18WRAwAQuRAp0eVS0MKkH1kCFiIEsyBg0x2ACUqPExvx-nsDMdlql%20McOEizvSshwuCZ%20AByABSsQgnNZyCktzZyHujwZbO4un4AFYAAyCmQcGQyVjY3FgfE-EnYqDkg6-alZWlwFmi4Gg8Hm0XSvjIADsACYlSK2XCEUyJYKOHbHjzkMkAO6aAWi5VC6RYnF4h5gf6%20fY0LLRQYjCDjSb-Gj-ZKpdLKBhugAKadGE2Q%20XksRgvWyACJTfWyqwGAAKLIEhIUt2KKCxZRQBT8YusACUngWgqgEDABCgIG1CQbTbK2T7A%20gCjKADo-WKsyvZs3ssW1-W-c3WmqNXjyHyMDsHvs4wmTG2u05iaT9ddkJzxU5MdWlvLV7wgR8HgASRAPUZ2oF9ZzfXQP0JXUyT-TkgxSaAzjwHEgJAmMwIfAAJEEwTAABheJ4K1AxX2mXxUISVB0N-f9LUowj1WI5BwIwcirTAGC4PMRD4yY99P2-PUxkwrjwR429YjwCAd3wzQ2wEp8IAnAB6fTkAVXjcVU9TNO0h9dNE2jzAMoyCHGCAYFACAxiAA)

Edit: on further reflection the generics of the `Form` interface itself is not really necessary, you could do something else like declare a basic `Form` interface and then `extend` it with each specific form:

```js
interface FormDataType {
  [key: string]: StringValue | NumberValue;
}

interface Form {
  data: FormDataType
};

interface FormA extends Form {
  data: {
    name: StringValue;
    age: NumberValue;
  }
};

interface FormB extends Form {
  data: {
    height: NumberValue;
    nickname: StringValue;
  }
};

const getFormValue = <
  F extends Form,
  P extends keyof F["data"]
>(
  form: F,
  property: P
) => {
    return form["data"][property].value as F["data"][P]["value"];
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing almost exactly what you wrote in your edit ^
```
type Value = StringValue | NumberValue

interface BaseFormData {
  [property: string]: Value
}

interface FormAData extends BaseFormData {
...
```
Thank you! Yeah the general lessons seems to be: formally enforce an invariant in the type system if possible. In this case, every "data object" property had the same signature but I needed to tell the compiler that explicitly. Thank you!

Comment: @VanceFaulkner cool, would you be willing to drop a link to a Playground example with more detail on your solution? Curious to see what you came up with.